# laser curved line detection using opencv and python_new

Tags: python, opencv, line, detection

[image: Original Image]

Hello, I am new to the opencv world. I would like to detect a bending edge by line laser triangulation. I have a picture with the line of the laser and would now like to edit the image so I only see an averaged lines (drawContour). The image was recorded only with the laser. The line is a little intertwined.

Now my questions / thought process: How can I convert the binarized (threshold) picture so that the line of a color value (everything white) and the rest is black?

Then I need a mean value (min-max, x, y) of all values ​​to characterize a line with the draw function. Is there a function for this?

This new mean value line then has to be in an array that I can do the triangulation. `np.array` `[]`?

In my previous code I have tried some filters. Unfortunately, I do not come to the result which I imagine. Which filter would be the best? And how do I get the rest over a certain threshold on white? How can I make pixels black which should not be there? What kind of problems do I have? Do I go wrong? Please help me, over every contribution I would be very happy.

Thanks Daniel

My Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Img1=cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/6.jpg',0)   
Img1=cv2.resize(Img1,(0,0),fx=0.5,fy=0.5)

#Thresh-Binär
retval,th1=cv2.threshold(Img1,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Thres- Otsu
retval2,th2=cv2.threshold(Img1,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Thresh-Adaptive+Gauss
th3=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(Img1,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, \
                      cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,2)
#Gauss 
blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(Img1,(5,0),4)
blur2=cv2.GaussianBlur(th1,(5,5),0)


kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(10,10))
skinmask=cv2.erode(Img1,kernel,iterations=3)
skinmask=cv2.dilate(Img1,kernel,iterations=3)
skinmask=cv2.GaussianBlur(skinmask,(3,3),1)
#Morpholo Filter/noise removal
kernel1 = np.ones((3,2),np.uint8) #np.unit=unsigned interger(0-255)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(blur,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)

#Contour finder
im2,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(skinmask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPRO    X_SIMPLE)

#kanten = cv2.Canny(opening,100,50)

#draw Contours
cnt=contours[0]
M=cv2.moments(cnt) #??
print(M)
Kontur=cv2.drawContours(Img1,contours,0,(255,255,255),5)
perimeter=cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)


cv2.imshow('Original',Img1)
cv2.imshow('Tresh',th1)
cv2.imshow('Tresh+Otsu',th2)
#cv2.imshow('TreshAdaptiv+Gauss',th3)
cv2.imshow('Kontur',Kontur)
#cv2.imshow('Tresh+Gaussian',blur2)
cv2.imshow('arc',perimeter)
cv2.imshow('Morph',opening)
cv2.imshow('skin',skinmask)

cv2.waitKey(0)     
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(len(contours))
```

Edit 28.05.2017

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcOJF.jpg)

Comment: Can you add another image showing what you actually want to find please?

Comment: In Example you can find my idea @MarkSetchell